# How does one interpolate between polar coordinates?

Tags: interpolation, polar-coordinates

I'm finding that when I try to use the standard methods of interpolation in polar space, the result is not what I would expect. For example, when interpolating between the following polar coordinates:

- $(3, 0)$
- $(1, \pi/2)$
- $(3, \pi)$
- $(1, 3\pi/2)$

one would expect the result to be an ellipse. However, using cosine interpolation, the result looks like [this](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MSwiZXEiOiIzKigxLSgxLWNvcyh0aGV0YSoyKSkvMikrMSooMS1jb3ModGhldGEqMikpLzIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDgwY2MiLCJ0aGV0YW1pbiI6IjAiLCJ0aGV0YW1heCI6IjJwaSIsInRoZXRhc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi00LjE1OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5MyIsIjQuMTU5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkzIiwiLTIuNTU5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk1NiIsIjIuNTU5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk1NiJdfV0-).

Is anyone aware of a different method that would produce the results I am looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to preserve the convexity of the shape, one should make sure that the function $r=r(\theta)$ has "flat" minima; in contrast, the maxima can and should be relatively sharp. Applied to your data, the cosine interpolation yields $r=2+\cos 2\theta$ while the ellipse would have equation $r=3/\sqrt{5-4\cos 2\theta}$. While the large-scale behavior of these functions is the same, their extrema [look rather different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHYLC.png).

You can fix this by preprocessing the $r$-values. Instead of $(r,\theta)$ pairs, interpolate between $(1/r^2,\theta)$ pairs and then apply the inverse function $1/\sqrt{r}$. In your problem, this means interpolating between

> $(1/9,0)$, $(1,\pi/2)$, $(1/9,\pi)$, $(1,3\pi /2)$

which yields $(5-4\cos 2\theta)/9$. Hence, the shape is $r=1/\sqrt{(5-4\cos 2\theta)/9}$ which is exactly the ellipse with your  four points as vertices.

To show that this works for shapes other than ellipses, I replaced the first point with $(5,0)$. The result is a [nice convex egg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmKnS.png) with equation $r= 15/\sqrt{121-8\cos \theta  -104 \cos 2\theta}$

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed, thanks!